# Maven: Install in local repository a jar using its ftp address

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ftp

I have my maven local repository located on a Windows machine and I am trying to install a jar in this repository using the ftp address of the jar(jar is located on a linux machine) using eclipse. Here are my `settings.xml` and `pom.xml`

**settings.xml**

```
   <server>
    <id>{server_address}</id>
    <username>username</username>
    <password>password</password>
    <configuration>
        <endpointChecking>false</endpointChecking>
    </configuration>
  </server>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.maven.bcone</groupId>
<artifactId>ArtifactName</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Sample</name>
<properties>
    <ics.version>17.4.5</ics.version>
    <ftp.dir>//sftp://username@{server_address}</ftp.dir>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.ics</groupId>
        <artifactId>cpi_omcs.jar</artifactId>
        <version>${ics.version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>BuildName</finalName>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install-cpi_omcs</id>
                    <phase>clean</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <file>${ftp.dir}/home/steve/myJars/cpi_omcs.jar</file>
                        <groupId>com.oracle.ics</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cpi_omcs</artifactId>
                        <version>${ics.version}</version>
                        <packaging>jar</packaging>
                        <generatePom>true</generatePom>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-file</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>{server_address}</id>
            <name>158_bcone</name>
            <url>sftp://username@{server_address}</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
  </project>
```

After running mvn:clean, I get below error

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install-file (install-cpi_omcs) on project BconeAdapter: The specified file '\\sftp:\username@{server_addres}\home\steve\myJars\cpi_omcs.jar' not exists -> [Help 1]

The jar file exists at the mentioned location but maven is not able to find it. What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you set also `{path_to_jar_on_server}`?

Comment: No, I have written it for representation purpose only. `{path_to_jar_on_server}` is actually valid path on server. Let me change it to avoid confusion.

Comment: You have _ftp.dir = //sftp://username@{server_address}_? Is leading `//` valid/needed? And how come those are backslashes `\\` in exception? Does Windows convert them?

Comment: 1. If I am not using the leading `//` slashes, then it interprets the path from eclipse workspace. e.g. If my workspace on Windows is located at: `D:/steve/java then without` `//` slashes the interpreted path is `D:/steve/java/sftp:/username@{server_address}`

2. The backward slash in exception is being converted by Windows itself I guess.

Comment: Why do you use ftp as protocol for install ? The default is using http(s) to deploy artifacts to a repository manager ...Why would you like to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do this using these maven plugins

```
<properties>
    <ics.version>18.1.3</ics.version>
    <temp.dir>./temp/</temp.dir>
    <ftp.dir>scp://username:password@server-address</ftp.dir>
    <ics.dir>/u01/app/oracle/lib</ics.dir>
</properties>

    <build>
    <finalName>MyProject</finalName>
    <plugins>

        <!-- DOWNLOAD THE JAR FILES TO A TEMP FOLDER ON THE LOCAL MACHINE -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>download-ftp-suite</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <url>${ftp.dir}:${ics.dir}</url>
                        <toDir>${temp.dir}</toDir>
                        <includes>
                            */**/*.jar
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>download</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
              </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <executions>

                <execution>
                    <id>install-one-of-the-downloaded-jars</id>
                    <phase>site</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <file>${temp.dir}one-of-the-downloaded-jars.jar</file>
                        <groupId>com.oracle.ics</groupId>
                        <artifactId>one-of-the-downloaded-jars</artifactId>
                        <version>${ics.version}</version>
                        <packaging>jar</packaging>
                        <generatePom>true</generatePom>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-file</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
               </executions>
        </plugin>
     </plugins>


    <extensions>
        <!-- Enabling the use of SSH IN ACCESSING FTP/SCP -->
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
</build>
```

**With these changes there is no need to add server details in settings.xml**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should be using `maven-wagon`. I am not sure if `maven-install-plugin` can handle network paths.

*The rest is total copy&paste from Apaches page as it is the minimun essential information needed to get the solution working*

From [Apache maven deploy plugin page](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/examples/deploy-ftp.html)

> In order to deploy artifacts using FTP you must first specify the use
>   of an FTP server in the distributionManagement element of your POM as
>   well as specifying an extension in your build element which will pull
>   in the FTP artifacts required to deploy with FTP:

```
<distributionManagement>
   <repository>
     <id>ftp-repository</id>
     <url>ftp://repository.mycompany.com/repository</url>
   </repository>
</distributionManagement>

<build>
   <extensions>
      <extension>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
         <artifactId>wagon-ftp</artifactId>
         <version>*version*</version>
      </extension>
   </extensions>
</build>
```

> Your settings.xml would contain a server element where the id of that
>   element matches id of the FTP repository specified in the POM above:

```
<settings>
   ...
   <servers>
      <server>
         <id>ftp-repository</id>
         <username>user</username>
         <password>pass</password>
      </server>
  </servers>
  ...
</settings>
```

> You should, of course, make sure that you can login into the specified
>   FTP server by hand before attempting the deployment with Maven. Once
>   you have verified that everything is setup correctly you can now
>   deploy your artifacts using Maven:

```
mvn deploy
```

Comment: Are u sure it will work for **installing** the jar. bcoz the solution is talking about **deploying** the jar to a remote location

Comment: When I tested it seemed to do just the right thing so copying jar & pom stuff to correct package/version directory under provided url. BUT: seems that it does not support `sftp` only `ftp`.

Comment: I am getting this error:
`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project BconeAdapter: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.maven.bcone:BconeAdapter:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.oracle.ics:cpi_omcs.jar:jar:17.4.5 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository`

Comment: Think it is not related. Why do you have as dependency the same artifact you're installing? Why the installing project  has it as dependency? Try to run without it.

Comment: I am trying to move the dependencies from remote ftp location to my local system repository i.e. I am moving jars from a Unix machine to my Windows machine and installing them in the local repository on Windows Machine. Deploying the project would move the project jar from Windows to UNIX,which I am not seeking.